# Binding a DataSource to a <DataList> From Server Side Code

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a very specific style on my website and I have a need for a `ComboBox` to allow users to either select a preset location or enter in their own. I was going to use the Ajax `Combobox` but it has it's own set styling and I can't get it to match the style of my other controls. As a result I've decided to make my own sort of combo box using some of the default controls provided.

I have everything I need except I can't find a way to set a `datasource` to the generic `<datalist>` control. I could hardcode the set locations as shown in my fiddle but I don't want to have to maintenance it this way when we add/remove locations. Any help? You can `DataBind` on a `<datalist>` but there is no `DataSource` property.

```
<input type="text" id="listLocations" list="dlLocations" runat="server" />
<datalist id="dlLocations" runat="server">
    <option value="Location1">Location 1</option>
    <option value="Location2">Location 2</option>
    <option value="Location3">Location 3</option>
</datalist>
```

**VB.NET; Creating Dummy Records**

```
Dim dsLocations As New DataSet
Dim dtLocations As New DataTable

dtLocations.Columns.Add("Description")

For i As Integer = 0 To 4
    dtLocations.Rows.Add("Location " & (i + 1))
Next

dsLocations.Tables.Add(dtLocations)

'dlLocations.DataSource = dsLocations.Tables(0).DefaultView
'dlLocations.DataBind()
```

I tried using an `<asp:datalist>` as my source but it wouldn't hide like the normal `<datalist>` would. It was able to bind but it would show beneath the textbox as a regular list.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlLocations"  runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Description")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hhaag18/fk13qgb8/

Comment: Why are you doing this in the code behind?  Why not do it using a [`<asp:SqlDataSource>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.7.2) object? You can add this into your control then provide properties for the developer to set.

Comment: @Paul I created an `<asp:SqlDataSource>` with ID of "sdsLocations" even though I'd prefer to do this in the code behind if possible. If I can't how am I now referencing this within my `<datalist>` ?

Comment: To be fair, I'd use a `Repeater` control - far better, without the ridiculous overheads of other templated controls.  With a `Repeater`, just set the `DataSourceId`.  It should be the same for the `DataList` (e.g. `<asp:DataList   ID="dlLocation" runat="server" DataKeyField="id"  DataSourceID="sdsLocation">`).

Comment: @Paul I am not using `<asp:Datalist>` as it does not provide the same functionality of hiding the list and only showing when the textbox is clicked on. I am forced to use the generic `<datalist>` which has no `DataSourceID`. The only way I think I can do it using my method is to create a backend javascript filled with the different options and then parse them in as individual `<options>`.

Comment: Ah!  Hence the confusion.  No problem.  You could try wrapping it all in an [`<asp:UpdatePanel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.7.2).